# Yii2 captcha refresh button

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using the default captcha implementation of the yii2 advanced framework. I have a problem: I want to add a refresh button to my captcha but I do not know how can I do it

Comment: for better user experience and save users time, please use google recaptcha. https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/. I configured in Yii2 and it goes well.

Answer (score 11):

Add captcha action to your controller, add captcha to your form, add field and validate rules for `captcha` to your model. Read more [here](http://yii2-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/adding-captcha.html).

And add button in view for update captcha image, like this:

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'captcha')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
    'imageOptions' => [
        'id' => 'my-captcha-image'
    ]
]); ?>

<?php echo Html::button('Refresh captcha', ['id' => 'refresh-captcha']);?>
<?php $this->registerJs("
    $('#refresh-captcha').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#my-captcha-image').yiiCaptcha('refresh');
    })
"); ?>
```

Comment: Using `registerJs` and mixing JavaScript with PHP code is considered bad practice. It's better to use [assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html) instead.

Comment: http://twoggle.com/blog/refreshable-captcha-yii2/  (basically using Vitaly's answer above but put into its own separate class extending Captcha, nice n elegant)